# QGIS, creating a mbtiles file from a custom shape

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mbtiles

I wonder if anyone can be of assistance, I am attempting to create a .mbtiles file from open street map data with open sea map data laid on top of it. I have been able to create the file successfully but I appear to be struggling to create a .mbtiles file from a custom shape, namely a shapefile -  that is, I can set the extent to cover a rectangular area, either by dragging the rectangle out, or selecting the current canvas, but if I choose a shape file the extents get set to odd numbers, its really small, and I don’t get the output I was expecting.

Now, it appears that an extent is just a rectangle, so can I achieve what I want? Or is that simply not possible using the generate XYZ tiles exporter. Is it possible at all?

Comment: What is your QGIS version? Have yout seen this article [Creating MBTile Files from QGIS 3.8](https://www.fulcrumapp.com/blog/mbtiles-from-qgis/)? Mind that MBTiles is storage for tiled data, like rendered map tiles, i.e. small rasters. You may inspect these threads as well [Converting Shapefiles to Mapbox Vector Tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208072/converting-shapefiles-to-mapbox-vector-tiles) and [Create vector tiles from GeoJSON or ShapeFile](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/custom-vector-from-shapefile-geojson/).

Comment: Hello, I am running 3.12.3. I have seen that article, and managed to make MBTitles which work fine. The trouble is the tilesets are huge, and one of the reasons is because when I am creating the extent, it looks like it can only be a rectangle, so i'm including a lot of data I don't actually want. If I could get the system to select the tiles based on a custom shape - this would radically reduce the file size.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't possible to do it using images. I had to bite the bullet and use vectors, still packed into tiles. It took weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and at least found a workaround to reduce the file size:
I simply covered the area NOT of interest with a plain coloured polygon (e.g. white).
In my case the final result for the mbtile filesize went from 400 mb to 150 mb after covering 60% of the area plain white.

The reason: Thanks to the image compression of png and jpeg, the file size can be dramatically reduced.
I.e.: a plain white 1000x1000 pixel png has a file size of about 4kb while one with the same image and colourful content might have some 250 kb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).